# Re-running failed KIF tests

Tags: ios, testing, xctest, kif-framework, kif

As you probably know, KIF tests can be flaky. I'm experimenting with trying to re-run a KIF test if it fails. Not sure if this is the best route but I am overriding the KIF failWithExceptions method to loop three times and on the 4th call the super of failWithException and stop the test. I just can't figure out how to actually launch the test again.

This is what I have now. Next step is to it the testCase and testName, and then invoke that test. Any thoughts?

Thanks

```
- (void)failWithException:(NSException *)exception stopTest:(BOOL)stop
{
    NSLog(@"Test Failed, running again");
    int testCount = 0;
    for(int i = 1;i <= 3; i++)
    {
        [self afterEach]; //call the afterEach method to get test in known state

        //this is where I want to re-run the test, maybe [XCtest ....] or  
        testCount += 1;
    }
    if(testCount==3)
    {
        [super failWithException:exception stopTest:stop];
    }
```

}